# Access Application using same ip within office network

Tags: java, networking

I've deployed one application developed using Java-Struts on one of my client's office. Application is web-based - So we hosted it on one the machine available in client's office - using static ip. The application runs fine(well I had couple of issues to deal with honestly). But when we were testing the application within client's environment - we came across odd issue.

If client needs to access the application inside their network - they need to use local ip address, something like this - 
http://192.168.1.12:8080/CTS

Outside the network - they need to use following url -
http://99.99.999.999:8080/CTS

How I can make sure client does not have to use 2 different urls to access this application? 
I went through few forums and got to know about host mapping and NAT forwarding, etc. I'm not a networking expert, So I really need some guidance of how to achieve this with right method. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked an answered many times on [sf], which would be the appropriate place for the question.

Answer (score 0):

For security reason the intranet IP(http://192.168.1.12:8080/CTS) is not exposed publicly.Have to check with the network team of Client whether the IP is publicly exposed if not then map local IP with domain/Static IP and that should be exposed publicly.If it is publicly exposed then within the network too the client can access intranet IP/domain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there anyway we can access application using static ip http://99.99.999.999:8080/CTS ?

Comment: Yes its possible.If the static IP is publicly exposed then we can access the application. That is you have to check with network team whether the IP   http://99.99.999.999:8080/CTS address is static which means the IP address does not change.